# Shell scripting advanced functions — How can I write a function to the following example?

Tags: function, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

doc1=docum1
doc2=docum2
doc3=
pack1=
pack2=package2
pack3=




if [ -n $doc1 ] || [ -n $pack1 ]; then
        echo "doc1 is $doc1"
        echo "pack1 is $pack1"
else
        echo "doc1 has empty value"
fi
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRQff.png)

How can I write a function if I have a bigger number of variables?

Comment: Do not post pictures of code; show the code in the question. AFAICS, though, the image is of the code you do show. Note that shell script is not suitable for snippets — they aren't executable JavaScript etc. It isn't clear what your problem is. There are no functions in the code shown. There are only 6 variables — that's not a lot. Bash supports arrays; if you're using another shell, it may do so also. The names like `pack1` suggest arrays. You should be using `[ -n "$doc1" ] || [ -n "$pack1" ]` with double quotes around your variables. The `else` clause is inaccurate (`pack1` is empty too).

Answer (score 0):

too simple .
Use this script :

```
#!/bin/bash 

doc1=docum1
doc2=docum2
doc3=
# ... 
doc102222=docum102222
pack1=
pack2=package2
pack3=
#...
pack30234324=package30234324

function checkExists() {
                v1=doc$1 
                v2=pack$2

                if [ -z ${!v1} ] ; then
                                echo "$v1 is empty" 
                elif [ -z ${!v2} ] ; then 
                                echo "$v2 is empty"
                else 
                                echo "doc is ${!v1}"
                                echo "pack is ${!v2}"
                fi
}

checkExists 1 1
echo "============================" 
checkExists 2 2
echo "============================" 
checkExists 102222 30234324
```

result is :

```
pack1 is empty
============================
doc is docum2
pack is package2
============================
doc is docum102222
pack is package30234324
```

Comment: Bash provides `nameref` to avoid variable indirection.

Comment: I know , Problem is about this question can not approve that . maybe he want load variables from a file , in this case can not iterate over index of variables .

Comment: You can't really assume the variable names are numbered sequentially from the question. There is nothing specified except *"How can I write a function if I have a bigger number of variables?"* There is nothing else provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and you want to be able to coordinate many different `document` and `package` *pairs*, then one approach would be to use two *indexed* arrays, one holding the `documents` and the other holding `packages` and you coordinate the documents and packages through a common index.

For example the first index applies to the first document and first package, the second to the next document and next package and so on and so forth. (**noting** that arrays in bash are zero-indexed, so actually index `0` corresponds to `document_1` and `package_1`)

Bash arrays can hold empty-values. So initializing the `doc` array as:

```
doc=( docum1 docum2 "" )
```

Results in a 3-element array with the 3rd element empty. And for your `pac` array:

```
pac=( "" package2 "" )
```

Where only the 2nd element has a value.

Putting it together with logic that checks if (1) both have values; (2) neither have a value; (3) only `document` has a value; and finally (4) only `package` has a value, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

doc=( docum1 docum2 "" )    ## index arrays for doc and pac
pac=( "" package2 "" )

docn=${#doc[@]}             ## numer of elements in doc array

## validate it is equal to number of elements in pac
if [ "$docn" -ne "${#pac[@]}" ]; then
    printf "error: unequal elements in 'doc' and 'pac' arrays\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

## loop over each index
for ((i=0; i<docn; i++)); do
    ## check if both have values
    if [ -n "${doc[i]}" ] && [ -n "${pac[i]}" ]; then
        printf "doc[%d] : %s\npac[%d] : %s\n" "$((i+1))" "${doc[i]}" "$((i+1))" "${pac[i]}"
    ## check if neither have values
    elif [ -z "${doc[i]}" ] && [ -z "${pac[i]}" ]; then
        printf "both doc[%d] and pack[%d] are empty\n" "$((i+1))" "$((i+1))"
    ## check if doc has value with empty package
    elif [ -n "${doc[i]}" ]; then
        printf "doc[%d] has empty value\n" "$((i+1))"
    ## otherwise doc is empty and package has value
    else
        print "pac[%d] is package without document\n" "$((i+1))"
    fi
    printf "\n"     ## tidy up with newline between output
done
```

(**remember** arrays in bash are zero-indexed. So `"$((i+1))` is used to print the results as `1, 2, 3, ...`)

Bash arrays can easily handle tens or hundreds of thousands of elements. It won't be the fastest script on earth with that many elements, but it won't be bad either.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash doc_and_pack.sh
doc[1] has empty value

doc[2] : docum2
pac[2] : package2

both doc[3] and pack[3] are empty
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood what you needed and if not leave a comment and I'm happy to help further. Let me know if you have further questions.